# Restart a POD on an Event

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have 2 pods - `P1` & `P2`.

- `P1` is running Nginx Proxy.
- `P2` running an envoy + custom application.

Due to some issue, the application stop responding to the requests redirected from `P1`.

But locally K8s probes are working fine in P2.
In this condition, Is it possible to restart the P2 based on the Error count seen in P1? (No service mash used in this setup).

Comment: `But locally K8s probes are working fine` - fix your probes first. Then let k8s do its job

Comment: Thanks. App fixing might take sometime. So trying for a workaround. How to handle, if the issue is related to network connection or external to application?

Answer (score 1):

> In this condition, Is it possible to restart the P2 based on the Error count seen in P1? (No service mash used in this setup).

You have several ways to accomplish that but they are a bit of "hack"

#### `CronJob`

Add `CronJob` which checks if the pod is responding and if not restart it

#### `kubectl get events`

Write your custom "Event Handler" to grab the stop events from the K8S events `kubectl get events`. you can fine-tune the events with `--field-selector` for example.

[image]